# coreplot dynamic graph line not visible

Tags: core-plot

I am working to have live graph displayed using coreplot. I am fetching the data every 2 seconds and passing that to the coreplot datasource but i dont see the line. i notice the x-axis (time axis) is updating correctly. Any advise please

```
  //listen to notification center and update the plot

    - (id) init
    {
        self = [super init];
        if (!self) return nil;
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(receiveDownloadDataNotification:)
                                                     name:@"Data"
                                                   object:nil];
        NSLog(@" downalodData notification listening");
        return self;
    }

    -(void)constructGraph1
    {

    // Create graph from a  theme
    graph1 = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CPTTheme *theme = [ CPTTheme themeNamed:kCPTPlainWhiteTheme];
    [graph1 applyTheme:theme];

    CPTGraphHostingView *hostingView = (CPTGraphHostingView *)self.view;
    hostingView.hostedGraph = graph1;

    graph1.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;

    //create x-axis time format

    NSTimeInterval refTimeInterval = [[NSDate date]
                                      timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss a"];

    CPTTimeFormatter *timeFormatter = [[CPTTimeFormatter alloc] initWithDateFormatter:dateFormatter];
    timeFormatter.referenceDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:0];

    // Setup plot space
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph1.defaultPlotSpace;
    plotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = NO;
    plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(refTimeInterval-(5*oneMin)) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(2*oneMin)];
    plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(100.0)];
    plotSpace.globalYRange=[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(100.0f)];

    //Line Styles
    CPTScatterPlot *boundLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];

    CPTMutableLineStyle *lineStyle = [boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    lineStyle.lineWidth         = 1.0f;
    lineStyle.lineColor         = [CPTColor blueColor];
    boundLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *majorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    majorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.75;
    majorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor colorWithGenericGray:0.2] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.75];
    CPTMutableLineStyle *minorGridLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    minorGridLineStyle.lineWidth = 0.25;
    minorGridLineStyle.lineColor = [[CPTColor whiteColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.1];

    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph1.axisSet;

    // X-Axes formatting
    CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    x.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromInteger(30);
    x.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromString(@"0");
    x.minorTicksPerInterval = 0;
    x.labelOffset=0;
    x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;
    x.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    x.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
    x.title=@"Time Axis";
    x.labelFormatter = timeFormatter;


    //Y-Axes formatting
    CPTXYAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.majorIntervalLength =  CPTDecimalFromInteger(10);
    y.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(refTimeInterval-oneMin);
    y.minorTicksPerInterval = 5;
    y.labelOffset = 0;
    y.majorGridLineStyle = majorGridLineStyle;
    y.minorGridLineStyle = minorGridLineStyle;
    y.preferredNumberOfMajorTicks = 10;
    y.minorTickLineStyle = nil;
    y.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInteger(0) length:CPTDecimalFromInteger(100)];
    y.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:0.0];
    y.title=@"Mbps";

    // Create a plot that uses the data source method
    CPTScatterPlot *dataSourceLinePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init] ;
    dataSourceLinePlot.identifier = @"graph Plot";
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataLineStyle = lineStyle;
    dataSourceLinePlot.dataSource = self;

    [graph1 addPlot:dataSourceLinePlot];
    graphDatatoPlot = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

}


-(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
{
    return graphDatatoPlot.count;
}



-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if ( [plot.identifier isEqual:@"graph Plot"] ){
        NSDecimalNumber *num = [[graphDatatoPlot objectAtIndex:index] objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:fieldEnum]];

        return num;
    }

    return 0;
}

- (void) receiveDownloadDataNotification:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"Data"])
    {
        NSLog(@"received item %@",[notification object]);
        [graphDatatoPlot addObject:[notification object]];
        [graph1 reloadData];
        CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graph1.defaultPlotSpace;

        NSTimeInterval aTimeInterval = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(aTimeInterval-(5*oneMin)) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(2*oneMin)];

        NSLog(@"plot count %i",graphDatatoPlot.count);
    }
}
```

just to test i am sending a constant value of 20 to the Notification center. Time is fired  OK, x-axis is updated but i dont see the actual line at 20 mark.

```
-(void)testTimer:(NSTimer *)Timer {



    NSTimeInterval timeNow= [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];


    NSMutableDictionary  *newData=  [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:timeNow], [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldX], 
                                           [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:20], [NSNumber numberWithInt:CPTScatterPlotFieldX],nil
                                           ] ;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Data" object:newData];

    NSLog(@"newdata is %@ %f",newData,timeNow);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data points are outside the `xRange`. Each data point is given a x-value of the current time, but the `xRange` is set to a range starting five minutes before the current time with a length of two minutes, meaning it ends three minutes before the current time.

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, i amended the code to include the current time in the intervel, but still dont see anything.
        plotSpace.xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(aTimeInterval-(1*oneMin)) length:CPTDecimalFromInt(2*oneMin)];

Comment: In the `testTimer:` method, make sure the dictionary that holds the new data point has keys for both `CPTScatterPlotFieldX` and `CPTScatterPlotFieldY`.